# Dictionary in javascript that has keys associated with objects

Tags: javascript, dictionary

I need to process a series of data, where each line has the user ID and the data I want to process. I thought a good solution would be to read these files and create a JSON where the keys are the ids and the values are all the data associated with that id.

```
[
  id1 : 
        {
          name: "..."
          age: "..."
          date_of_birth: "..."
        },
  id2 : 
        {
          name: "..."
          age: "..."
          date_of_birth: "..."
        },
  ...
]
```

However, I'm not sure how I can dynamically add more information to the objects associated with the ID. At each reading of the line of my file, I must look in my dictionary for the ID. If there is already a record of this ID in the dictionary, I should just add a new line in the object associated with it. Otherwise, I must create this key/value pair and add a new line to the object associated with it. Preferably, I would like to build this dictionary in descending order of ids. Any idea how I can build this structure?

Comment: Sounds like you should be using a [Map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map)

Comment: A side comment about the JSON structure in your question - the top-level markup should be `{ }` not `[ ]` since it has keys. Also, JSON keys can only be strings and unlike JavaScript syntax, the key names must be inside double quote marks.

Answer (score 0):

if one id can have several instances , it is better to use this structure

```
{
  "id1" : [
        {
          name: "name1",
          age: 1,
          date_of_birth: "date1"
        }
       ],
    
  "id2" :[ 
        {
          name: "name2",
          age: 2,
          date_of_birth: "date2"
        }
       ]
}
```

Comment: What is `Dictionary<string , List< T >>` when it relates to JavaScript? May you explain for non-TS users?

Comment: @evolutionxbox Thanks, I already lost my mind

Comment: Nah, you haven't.